# upload / download permissions

Tags: permissions, upload, chmod

I currently have a folder which the public uploads files to.

I want to be able to download these files via a link, but not to be able to browse the upload folder. But at the same time, i need to keep that folder writable for uploads.

What permissions would I need to set?

Cheers, 
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `.htaccess` file in your current folder, or create it if it doesn't exist.

If `Options Indexes` exists modify it to `Options -Indexes` or else add `Options -Indexes` as a new line.

Save the file and exit.

You might need to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best with an `.htaccess` file inside your upload folder, add this code inside the `.htaccess` file to prevent directory listings for that folder:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Or

```
Options -Indexes
```

With IndexIgnore you can change the wildcard * to a list of extensions you want to ignore.  This allows you to do something like:

```
IndexIgnore *.gif *.jpg
```

Which will not show any gif or jpg's in the directory listing but everything else.

This will allow you to keep whatever permissions your using now but prevent people from directly viewing everything you have uploaded in that folder.